# How may I use Postman to connect to laravel-websockets running within Docker

Tags: docker, postman, laravel-8, pusher, laravel-websockets

I want to test receiving events broadcasted from my laravel app via laravel-websockets.  The app and websockets are running successfully in docker and I have supervisor keeping everything up and running.  My problem is, with Postman's websocket feature, I cannot connect to the websockets server running within docker (ws://127.0.0.1:6001). I get 404.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '2'

services:
  ace-contact-import:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8787:80"
      - "6001:6001"
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/
    tty: true
  composer:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker/composer/Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - ace-contact-import
    volumes_from:
      - ace-contact-import
    tty: true
  redis:
    image: redis:alpine
    container_name: ace-contact-import-redis
    command: redis-server --appendonly yes --requirepass "${REDIS_PASSWORD}"
    volumes:
      - ./data/redis:/data
    ports:
      - "8002:6379"
volumes:
  logvolume01: {}
```

**websockets.php**

```
'apps' => [
        [
            'id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
            'name' => env('APP_NAME'),
            'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
            'path' => env('PUSHER_APP_PATH'),
            'capacity' => null,
            'enable_client_messages' => false, // peer-to-peer client messages
            'enable_statistics' => false,
        ],
    ],
```

**broadcasting.php**

```
'connections' => [

        'pusher' => [
            'driver' => 'pusher',
            'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY', 'app-key'),
            'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET', 'app-secret'),
            'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID', 'app-id'),
            'options' => [
                'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
                'host' => env('LARAVEL_WEBSOCKETS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
                'port' => env('LARAVEL_WEBSOCKETS_PORT', 6001),
                'scheme' => env('LARAVEL_WEBSOCKETS_SCHEME', 'http'),
                'encrypted' => false, // todo
                'useTLS' => env('PUSHER_SCHEME') === 'https', // todo
            ],
        ],
```

***.env***

```
PUSHER_APP_ID=12345
PUSHER_APP_KEY=ABCDEFG
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=HIJKLMNOP
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

LARAVEL_WEBSOCKETS_HOST=host.docker.internal # also tried 127.0.0.1
LARAVEL_WEBSOCKETS_PORT=6001
LARAVEL_WEBSOCKETS_SCHEME=http

# For Echo (Client side)
MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a raw ws connection to your websocket instance:

```
ws://localhost:6001/app/abcdef
```

abcdef is the *PUSHER_APP_KEY* which should match what's in your .env file.
If your port is something other than 6001, change it in the URL.

Once connected, you may compose a message within Postman to subscribe to your channel:

```
{
   "event":"pusher:subscribe",
   "data":{
      "auth":"",
      "channel":"your-channel-name-here"
   }
}
```

That's it!  As messages are broadcast from the server, they'll appear in the messages page at the bottom of the screen.

Comment: If I duplicate the postman websocket request and then connect using the above method and subscribe to `"your-channel-name-here"` how to I send a message that it is received on previously connected-subscribed instance. BTW, Thanks a lot for this answer help a lot in debugging ws.

Comment: @karmendra Postman will allow you to establish 2 separate connections to your websocket server with no issues.  You may run into problems trying to connect 2 tabs to the same private channel AFAIK.  See the "Defining broadcast events" example on how you would send a message from your websocket application to a particular user: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/broadcasting#defining-broadcast-events

Comment: What do you put in the `auth` field in case you want to connect to a private channel

Comment: Never mind, I figured out how to authenticate private channels

Comment: It'd be nice to share it @Edgar

Comment: @leevanoetz What goes there would be the authentication token returned from say a /broadcasting/auth api

Answer (score 0):

To subscribe to a private channel, you have to follow a few extra steps:

1. Create a raw connection: If it's successful, you can see the `socket_id` in the response. Keep this socket_id somewhere safe.

> ws://localhost:6001/app/{PUSHER_APP_KEY}

3. Make another HTTP call to the `broadcast/auth` endpoint (it's by default configured on Laravel). You need to have a valid Bearer auth token or session to validate the user. And the socket_id from step one and the private channel name. As a valid request, you will get an "auth" value in the response.

> curl --location 'http://{SITE_URL}/broadcasting/auth' 
> --header 'Authorization: Bearer {AUTH_TOKEN}' 
> --header 'Accept: application/json' 
> --header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' 
> --data-urlencode 'socket_id={SESSION_ID}' 
> --data-urlencode 'channel_name={PRIVATE_CHANNEL_NAME}'

3. Finally, in the Postman websocket compose screen you need to enter the auth value for subscribing to the private channel.

> {     "event": "pusher:subscribe",    "data": {       "auth":
> "abcdef:2ac9054fffbe42b2d6ef5227e1f6ea69477307b3d4134a46da2f29c8d985400c",
> "channel": "private-App.Models.User.1"  } }

That's it. Hope it will be helpful for someone.